# Do we have ResultSet object feature of value retrieval in JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Native Query to fetch the data for a large report. I have used ResultStream to stream the data in batches to avoid OOM. However, my requirement is to fetch the data based on the fieldNames so as to generate the jasper report.

We were able to do this using spring Jdbc using ResultSet as it as the method as

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-java.lang.String-

**rs.getObject(fieldName);**

I am looking for a similar feature in JPA.

As a workaround to fetch the field values, I had used Java reflection but it is impacting the performance a lot due to high CPU utilization.